# Nested loops in C++ and user input

Tags: c++, loops, nested-loops

Pretty new here to programming, and I have an assignment where I need to achieve the following:

- ask for total amount of people
- get each of their names
- allow user to enter up to 5 scores for each person
- if there are less than 5 scores for a given person, inputting -100 will stop it

So far I have written this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string personName;
    int totalPerson, personScoreCounter;
    double personGrade, personGradeTotal;

    cout << "Input total amount of people: ";
    cin >> totalPerson;

   for (int person = 1; person <= totalPerson; person++)
   {
       cout << "Input name for person " << person << ": ";
       getline(cin, personName);
       cin.ignore();

       while ( (personGrade != -100) && (personScoreCounter <= 5) )
       {
           cout << "Input up to 5 scores for " << personName << " (-100 to end): ";
           cin >> personGrade;

           if (personGrade >= 0 && personGrade <= 100) // valid range of scores
           {
               personGradeTotal += personGrade;
               personScoreCounter++;
           }
           else
           {
               cout << "Input only scores from 0-100" << endl;
           }

           cout << "Input up to 5 scores for " << personName << " (-100 to end): ";
           cin >> personGrade;
       }
}

    // calculate averages and other stuff in here.

    return 0;
}
```

After getting their name, only the last `cout` inside the while loop seems to execute first, then it starts from the top and so on until the `for` loop hits the end depending on `totalPerson`. I know I'm missing a few things in here, probably in the order of operations and also the way I am executing my loops, but I just can't see it. Could any of you guys with experience in the language please give me any pointers as to what's happening here and how I can fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Might it have to do with the `cin.ignore()`?

Comment: You haven't initialized `personGrade` or `personScoreCounter`, this is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I appreciate it sir and will await your answer. @chrisb2244

Comment: You might also consider changing your line from `Enter up to 5 scores for NAME:` to `Enter score #(counter) for NAME:` or similar, so that it reads 'Enter score #1 for MyName: (-100 to end)', 'Enter score #2 for MyName: (-100 to end)', ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `while` group, you only want to use your `cout` line once (at the beginning looks good).

Your first check should be for `==-100` or similar, since as it is now, you'll get a "Input only scores from 0 to 100" message if you enter `-100`.

You should keep a `cin.ignore();` call after each use of `cin >> VARIABLE`, since then you will drop the EoL character.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int totalPerson;

    cout << "Input total number of people: ";
    cin >> totalPerson;
    cin.ignore();

   for (int person = 1; person <= totalPerson; person++)
   {
       int personScoreCounter=0;
       double personGrade = -1, personGradeTotal=0;
       string personName;

       cout << "Input name for person " << person << ": ";
       std::getline(cin, personName);

       while ( (personGrade != -100) && (personScoreCounter < 5) )
       {
           cout << "Input up to 5 scores for " << personName << " (-100 to end): ";
           cin >> personGrade;
           cin.ignore();

           if (personGrade == -100) {
               break;
           } else if (personGrade >= 0 && personGrade <= 100) {
               personGradeTotal += personGrade;
               personScoreCounter++;
           } else {
               cout << "Input only scores from 0-100" << endl;
           }
       }

    // calculate averages and other stuff in here.
    double avg = personGradeTotal / personScoreCounter;
    cout << "Avg = " << avg << endl;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Some of your variables also needed to move *inside* the `for` loop.

Additionally I changed the limits on the `personScoreCounter` to [0:4] rather than [1:5] - this way you can use it for averaging more easily.

Comment: Note that like @user657267 commented on the question, you should define (and not just declare) the variables that might be used without assignment. For example, using the `+=` operator on `personGradeTotal` without giving `personGradeTotal` a value first is bad news (I think - check with a language-lawyer style question).

Answer (score 0):

You might also try cin.getline() instead of getline(std::cin , ... ):

```
int max_length = 30;
std::cin.getline(personName, max_length, '\n'); // \n is option termination.
```

This allows whitespaces in the input also.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/